# Create a Proxy using Python to pass NTLM credentials to another Proxy

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, proxy

I have an issue where we have setup a NTLM proxy on the corporate level, but we have some code that we do not own that does not support NTLM proxies.  Is there a way to create a proxy to automatically pass the NTLM information needed using Python?

I would prefer to be able to just stand up the proxy as needed when the script is run at given times.

Is this possible to do?  Can anyone provide a sample on how to do this?
Samples can be given in Python 3.4 or 2.7.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at these:

[NTLM Authorization Proxy Server](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/)

[Python NTLM](https://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/)

Comment: @toasteex - yes I have that they didn't meet my needs.

Comment: I am looking for something that I can stand up on the fly through code.